# Checking satisfiability for matrix valued function

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am trying to multiply 2 matrices of 2*2 order. One of the matrix contains an unknown parameter "k1". I want to check a satisfiable solution that for which value of k1. The product of two matrices will be equal to the third one. 
Note: I dont want to convert the multiplication into a linear relation or set of equation I want to manipulate it as matrices.

Here is where I am stuck.

```
k1 = Int ('k1')

x = [ [ Int("x_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(2) ] 
     for i in range(2) ]

a =((1,k1),(3,4))

b =((1,1),(1,1))

c= ((3,3),(7,7))

s = Solver()
s.add(a[0][1]>0)
s.add(a*b==c)
if s.check() == sat:
m = s.model()
r = [ [ m.evaluate(x[i][j]) for j in range(2) ] 
      for i in range(2) ]
print_matrix(r)
else:
print "failed to solve"
```

Any way Out?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is

```
k1 = Int ('k1')

x = [ [ Int("x_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(2) ] 
 for i in range(2) ]

a =((1,k1),(3,4))

b =((1,1),(1,1))

c= ((3,3),(7,7))

s = Solver()
eq1= a[0][1]>0
eq2 =[[sum(a[i][k]*b[k][j] for k in range(2)) == c[i][j] for i in range(2) ]
         for j in range(2) ]
s.add(eq1)
s.add(eq2[0][0])
s.add(eq2[0][1])
s.add(eq2[1][0])
s.add(eq2[1][1])
print s             
print s.check()             
m = s.model()
print m
```

and the corresponding output is

```
[k1 > 0, 1 + k1*1 == 3, True, 1 + k1*1 == 3, True] 
sat 
[k1 = 2]
```

Please run this example online  [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/plfL)